# installing windows 10 with only ubuntu 16.04 currently on ssd

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

So i have a x220 with the only os on there being ubuntu 16.04 on my 500 gb samsung evo drive. I have windows 10 on a thumb drive that I want to install alongside ubuntu so that I can dual boot them. If I install windows, will it overwrite ubuntu and mess it up? I heard this happens, but is it hard to fix? Or should I plug my ssd into another computer and wipe it, and start fresh? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb is to install Windows first and then install Ubuntu second whilst selecting the "dual boot" option. That said, you don't have to wipe out Ubuntu, but create a partition for Windows to be installed into. In your case I'd go 400GB for windows and 100GB for Ubuntu. It all depends on where your multi-media files and games will be stored of course but I presume the bulk would be in Windows.

I've been hearing horror stories of how Windows 10 updates wipe out Linux in some situations (fast boot?). So backups are more important than ever today.

Comment: okay thanks! I literally will actually never use windows 10. I study computer science so I am mostly on ubuntu, and only want windows 10 in case I happen to need it for something. I think I will go ahead and just wipe my ssd, reinitialize it, then install windows, then ubuntu. Ubuntu currently contains nothing but many .hpp and .cpp files from programming that I already backed up. Does this sound like a good plan? I guess I will never update windows 10 now either! haha, also, if i select "something else" on the ubuntu menu, that will also set me up for dual booting? I want to create 18gb swap.

Comment: [continuing above post], for hibernation.

Comment: If you're going to dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu, you'll need to disable FAST BOOT and HIBERNATION in Windows. Ubuntu won't hibernate by default. So you don't need a 18GB swap. Set swap to 1-1.5 physical RAM size. Cheers, Al

Comment: how do i disable fast boot and hibernation in windows 10? Really? I read on so many forums to double your swap partition(which I can always get rid of but not add to it?), and you can tweak things to get it to hibernate? Also, the "something else" option is the same as dual booting, correct?

Comment: Swap = RAM size x 2 is a common formula when RAM <= 4 GB I believe. When you have more than 4GB some suggest swap isn't even necessary. Definitely my system with 8GB doesn't need swap. If the amount of swap is set based on misbehaved programs eating up RAM then that number is theoretically infinite when things go wrong. Type "free -t" in terminal to monitor RAM and SWAP usage totals.

Answer (score 0):

I install booth sistem in my samsung laptop, is preferible you install windows first is you use EFI boot, later UBUNTU (will install grub and you can always choose to boot windows or ubuntu); but in any case if you "overwrite" the boot info you can alway use a "Ubuntu live CD/USB" to install **`grub`** again, is very easy. Or if you like graphical interface install **`GrubCustomizer`** in ubuntu and fix the dual boot.

Grub will give you access to windows or ubuntu.

You can check also **`REFIND`** to have a *nice* graphical way to choose boot any OS (correctly installed).

Best regards.